# Angular application unable to open in windows operating

Tags: angularjs, node.js, linux, npm, bower

We are using windows 8.1 for one angular application. Installed the bower and npm, also installed node server.

We can see the login page after npm start but after login success we are not able to redirect. It showing error

> Cannot GET /components/home.html

After inspect element Console error like this:

```
angular.js:11038 GET http://localhost:8081/components/home.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Header:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8081/components/home.html
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:8081
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response:

```
Cannot GET /components/home.html
```

But it is working on linux machine perfectly. We are using .Net web api so we want to use one machine for both application.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have tested on Linux and it works, I would say it is a configuration in paths the server that it is serving the assets. If you are using Express or Webpack to serve you React code, they have good support for Windows, so probably is a local configuration issue.

Try checking for any static paths, e.g. `./foo/bar` and replacing them with a more Windows-friendly syntax, for example:

```
const path = require("path")

path.join("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: Yes your guess is correct but I am unable to set static path also. Same code is working on Linux that is issue. If it not work then we will fix but how differ in OS.